# psad: do not block access to HTTP

Tags: security, iptables, firewall, psad

I want to block intruders via `psad`, but HTTP and HTTPS should not be blocked. For example, if someone is scanning my dedicated server via `nmap`, `psad` should block him for 2 hours, but he should still see the contents from my domain.

I set `AUTO_BLOCK_TIMEOUT` to a value of 7200, so everyone scanning me is completely blocked for 2 hours. Woefully the attacker is also blocked from seeing my webpage, which is not my intention.

Is there any possibility to set up a partial blockage via `psad`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using SCAN_TIMEOUT

I would assume that if `psad` detects scanning attacks from some nefarious IP address that it wholesale blocks it for the duration of time set in `AUTO_BLOCK_TIMEOUT`.

If you just want to block scanning attacks then from the manual I would say you might want to use this timeout instead:

```
SCAN_TIMEOUT                        3600;
```

*excerpt*

> SCAN_TIMEOUT
>
> Defines the number of seconds psad will use to timeout scans (or other
>   suspect traffic) associated with individual IP addresses. The default
>   value is 3600 seconds (one hour). Note the SCAN_TIMEOUT is only used
>   if ENABLE_PERSISTENCE is set to "N".

#### Autoblocking with psad

If you look through the [FAQ](https://cipherdyne.org/psad/docs/faq.html) there's actually a section that discourages you from using `psad` in this manner.

> 3.3. Is it a good idea to set ENABLE_AUTO_IDS="Y" to automatically block scans?
>
> In general no, and this feature is disabled by default. The reason for
>   this is that a scan can be spoofed from any IP address (see the -S
>   option to nmap). If psad is configured to automatically block scans
>   then an attacker can spoof a scan, say, from www.yahoo.com and then
>   you will be parsing your firewall ruleset to discover why you can't
>   browse Yahoo's website, (or you can just execute "psad --Flush" to
>   remove any auto-generated firewall rules). Also, an advanced scanning
>   technique called the TCP Idle Scan requires that scan packets are
>   spoofed by the attacker from a seemingly unrelated IP address from the
>   viewpoint of the target. Nmap implements the Idle scan with its -sI
>   option, and a good explanation of the technique can be found [here](http://nmap.org/book/idlescan.html).

#### So can I leave ports 80/443 unaffected?

In looking at the documentation I don't see how you could achieve this, except by crafting your own rules that would get used when an attack is detected.

*excerpt*

> IPTABLES_AUTO_RULENUM
>
> Defines the specific rule number that psad will use to add
>   auto-generated iptables blocking rules in the INPUT, OUTPUT, and
>   FORWARD chains (ENABLE_AUTO_IDS must be set to "Y" for this keyword to
>   be used). The default value is "1".

Comment: I appreciate your diligent answer. Basically you answered what I would like to learn. I tested `SCAN_TIMEOUT` combined with `ENABLE_PERSISTENCE = N`, but `psad` is again blocking all traffic to my server from that ip the scan was initiated from, especially HTTP/HTTPS is blocked further on. I'm afraid `psad` is not the tool I'm looking for. Beside `fail2ban`, which I'm using, too, I'm in need of a solution to block scans only and grant access to HTTP/HTTPS at the same time.